# Each square of an infinite board colored with 1 of 2 colors. Expected value of inverse of size of monochromatic region is $\ge 1/8.$

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

I managed to reduce a tricky problem to showing the following:

> Each square of an infinite board is independently colored either black
> or white with probability $1/2.$ For a square $X,$ let $|X|$ denote
> the size of the monochromatic region containing $X.$ Prove that
> $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{|X|}\right] \ge 1/8.$

Through careful analysis, I found that the probability the region has size $1,2,3,4$ is $1/16, 1/32, 15/2^9, 35/2^{10}$ respectively. This means the expected value is at least $\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{64} + \frac{5}{2^9} + \frac{35}{2^{12}} \approx 0.0964.$ Unfortunately, this is not large enough, and I have no idea about how close the infinite sum is to $1/8.$ Finding a closed form for $p(|X|=k)$ seems infeasible. Does anyone have an idea for how to proceed?

Comment: Connected : https://sites.math.washington.edu/~reu/papers/current/jacob/clusters

Comment: @JeanMarie: That link cites Putnam 2005; but the problem is actually from Putnam 2004.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I was trying to be helpful. People might want to look it up.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, I thought the comment was issued by the asker ! Your comment can indeed be helpful.

Comment: As remarked by @TonyK, it is (more or less) problem n°5 of 2004 Putnam competition https with its text and a solution there https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2004.pdf . Were you aware of this fact ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. This is my approach to solving the problem. I want to see if the approach works instead of giving up and starting over.

Comment: Next time, please give the origin of the problem you want to solve. It will help  people who can potentially help you and prevent them to spend hours reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @JeanMarie Why would they be reinventing the wheel? I asked them to prove the problem I gave, not the problem which motivated my problem.

Comment: How do you know that your statement is true?

Comment: A general attitude in research is **to provide all relevant information**. Clearly, the origin of the problem is not yours, as TonyK just said you, the 1/8 objective does come from the Putnam competition.

Comment: @JeanMarie: this problem is not the same as the Putnam problem.